# ReactJS image file not found after npm run dist

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm working on a project where we need to compile an application for deployment. When I run the app in a server on my local machine it works perfectly, but after compiling the project it can't find the file because it has the wrong location: `/assets/12912bc94b5dcb7715a465d360537279.png` when it should be `assets/12912bc94b5dcb7715a465d360537279.png` (without the leading slash).

Here's the code in my component:

```
var logoPNG = require('../images/GS G favicon.png');
```

then:

```
<img className="img-responsive" width="45" height="45" alt="Brand" src={logoPNG} />
```

I am building the project using the default setup from https://github.com/newtriks/generator-react-webpack. I'm pretty new with webpack so I'm not sure which part of this code I should copy/ paste specifically, but just let me know and I will paste the appropriate part of the code.

Comment: try to use image without space in the name

Answer (score 0):

I tracked down the way to fix the issue, ends up it was the `publicPath` parameter that needed to change.

From this:

```
module.exports = {
  srcPath: srcPath,
  publicPath: '/assets/',
  port: dfltPort,
  getDefaultModules: getDefaultModules
};
```

to this:

```
module.exports = {
  srcPath: srcPath,
  publicPath: 'assets/',
  port: dfltPort,
  getDefaultModules: getDefaultModules
};
```

Notice `publicPath` is missing a beginning slash in the working example.